# Read cookies from nodejs in angular side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies

I am creating a project using angular and nodejs. I have a problem in my code. I am setting the cookies in nodejs and wants to read the angular side. I don't know how can I achieve this.

Here is setting the cookie

```
cookies = {expire : new Date(new Date().getTime()+20*60*1000), maxAge : 600000, httpOnly : true, secure : true};
res.cookie('cookiename', "cookievalue", cookies);
```

In angularjs:

```
console.log(document.cookie) //get blank value
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AngularJS api for that:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the values is a matter of using the [$cookie.get(key)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies#get) method:

```
console.log( $cookie.get('cookiename') ); // cookie value
```

In order to persist your cookies between requests to the server, use this config in Angular:

```
angular.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
})
```

This will send the cookie data back to the server on XHR calls to your nodejs server.